# Update multitables using one form in symfony+Doctrine

Tags: mysql, forms, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Hi I am building a registration system in symfony. It has three models -User, jobSeeker and employer. Jobseeker and employer inherit user.
There are 4 steps in the jobseeker registration process, in the first step users have to enter their login detail & it will be added to the user table. In the next steps user has to enter his personal details, it will be added to the jobseeker table.

I want to update the user table and jobseeker table using one form, how can I do it??
(For example address and tp number are in the user table, but it will be updated in the second step)

---

**Thankyou for ur replies**

It is working

what I did was

**In my dao class**

```
 public function updateStep($step,$address, $phone, $id)
    {

        Doctrine_Query::create()
          ->update('User u')
          ->set('u.step', '?', $step)
          ->set('u.address', '?', $address)
          ->set('u.telephone', '?', $phone)
          ->where('u.user_id = ?', $id)
          ->execute();
    }
```

**In the form class**

```
public function updateStep()
    {       
            $step = $this->getValue('step');
            $phone = $this->getValue('phone');
            $address = $this ->getValue('address');
            $id = $this->getValue('user_id');

            $updateStep = $this->getUserManagementService()->updateStep($step, $address, $phone, $id);
            return $updateStep;
        }
```

Finally in the registration action

```
$this->form->updateStep();
```

It is working but am I doing it in the right way or is there any easier way exist?

Answer (score 0):

Simply ... you can create new object from User and new object from jobseeker in first step and put this object in session and in step two retrieve this object from session and update it with data

and in last step save those two objects.